# Drupal 6 mail sender is set to 'Nobody' even though 'from' is specified

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to send an e-mail where the sender is specified. Instead i get Nobody@host.edu

```
$test='example body'.$random_String;
$message3 = array(
  'to' => 'fake_user@place.com',
  'from' => 'fake_sender@place.edu',
  //'from' => variable_get('site_mail', 'admin@example.com'), //alternative doesn't work either
  'subject' => t('Example subject'),
  'body' => $test,
  'headers' => array(),
);

drupal_mail_send($message3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation for the [`drupal_mail_send()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail_send/6) function. You're not providing the right parameters to `drupal_mail_send()`. You're missing the `id` key.
Plus, this function already uses PHP's `mail()` so you don't have to use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use good old php mail() function
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php